# Do I need to set up or create a node on my computer to bake tezos?

Tags: node, baking, baking-node

Mack B, I have watched your youtube video. I am kind of new to this and have done very little code work many years ago. But I do believe I can follow your steps 1 by 1. But my question is: Do I have to actually code and set up this "node" thing in order for me to bake with my 8000 Tezos? Are there any other options? Is there a program or an App or any other way to Bake without doing all that code stuff?

Also, If I have to create the node, will that coding be fine to use for years to come? Or will I have to insert new coding and updates as time passes? And how would I know or find out about that stuff? I am sorry for all the newbie questions. But I am extremely interested and highly motivated to learn. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, you have to compile the tezos code from scratch. There is a docker option if you are familiar with that. If you are not, it's probably even more complicated to get working. There used to be a Windows-GUI option, but that is no longer maintained and ceased working properly almost a year ago. Unfortunately there is no easy button and it will require some basic linux skills to get right. You will also need to forward port 9732 from your home router to whichever computer is running the tezos-node so that other nodes can talk to you.

If you follow all the instructions, it's not that complicated. It's mostly copy/paste/enter. You will eventually have several "programs" (also known as "binaries" in the linux world): `tezos-node` (the actual node that communicates with others), `tezos-baker-006-PsCARTHA`  (the actual baking program), and `tezos-endorser-006-PsCARTHA` (the program which injects endorsements).

You will need to have all 3 of these binaries running at all times. I recommend finding a tutorial on the linux tool `screen` so that each binary continues to run in the background in case you accidentally close one of the terminal windows.

The `tezos-node` will stay in communication with the entire network, receiving blocks from other nodes. When it is your turn to bake or endorse, those binaries will automatically create and inject their payloads into the network using your node.

The computer running tezos should have an SSD with around 30GB free space, and at least 2GB of RAM. Always-on internet and power are also crucial.

Lastly, no, this will not be good for years to come. You will need to update the code periodically as bug fixes and features are added. Best place to find these updates are on reddit.com/r/tezos

If all of this sounds too much, instead of self-baking, you can delegate your tokens, known as 'tez' (not tezzie), to a baking group. That group will bake your stake on your behalf and send you the rewards every few days. You can find a list of bakers at https://baking-bad.org/ Keep in mind that delegation is NOT transfer, and that you retain 100% control of all tokens, even when delegating.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for that response! I have found some instructions on

https://medium.com/@tezbaker.io/tezos-mainnet-setting-up-home-baking-4bf258a9fd30

Is this a good source to follow? If it is do you know of any videos that sort of follow along step by step? I can't really find anything on youtube that's a complete video, following these steps clearly.. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, good article. Skip the section on Snapshots, that will only confuse you. The MackB video you watched is the only video I found on actually setting up a node.